# Prevent polygon feature (catchment) overlap for land-use extraction using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, catchment

My aim is to calculate catchments for around 150 points and to extract land-use variables for them. In order to do so I need a vector dataset where no polygons overlap. This, however, seems to be a challenging task.

Presume, that I already calculated the catchments for all 150 points (see Figure 1; here only points 1-6 are visualized):

- How do I get from the overlapping catchment features in Figure 1 to the none overlapping catchment features in Figure 2?
- How can I associate the catchment features to previous overlaps? I thought of adding up the IDs (see 'Sum ID Overlap' in the attribute table in Figure 2). Can this  be done automatically?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?

Comment: I momentarily have access to QGis and ArcGIS. But I am also open to other solutions. I am thinking about calculating the catchments with Whitebox (https://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/mapping-watersheds-in-whitebox-gat/) or Grass (which I am not familiar with and would have to learn)

Comment: I think you should choose one to focus your question on. Otherwise this will be too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: If this can be easily done with QGis then I would prefer this solution. If not, ArcGIS will do.